# Buffer unpacking not optimized away , However only using 1d Numpy array

Tags: cython

I got a problem with an inline function in cython

```
cdef inline int binary_search(np.ndarray[np.float_t,ndim=1] cumsum, double rdn):
  cdef int mi=0,ma=len(cumsum)-1,pos 
  while True:
    if ( mi > ma):
      break
    pos = (mi+ma) / 2
    if (rdn <= cumsum[pos] ):
      ma=pos-1
    else:
      mi=pos+1
  return mi-1
```

However, I get the following problem:  Buffer unpacking not optimized away.

I heard that this is an issue when dealing with multidimensional arrays, but this is not the case for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I just had the same problem, and it was fixed by not using inline.  Theory: Cython normally optimizes numpy array access by accessing the underlying data buffer directly.  Perhaps it is for some reason not able to do this optimization in an inline function?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same warning using `Cython 3.0.0a10`.
What jcrudy says in the comment is true, namely, removing the `inline` would removed the warning.
Nevertheless, the warning is likely suggesting that directly passing an array, rather then a memory view would cause an overhead in the function call.
This is described in the [Cython documentation](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html).

In my case using a memory view, rather then a an array as argument, solved the problem without the need to remove the inline.
The above function would then look like this (if using float32):

```
cdef inline int binary_search(np.float32_t[:] cumsum, double rdn):
```

Keep in mind that creating the memory-view adds a little overhead, but since in your function you are not modifying the `cumsum` it would make perfectly sense to pass a memory view as argument to the function.

Comment: `np.ndarray[:]` looks very very odd to me. It's a memoryview of Numpy arrays?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was indeed wrong. The following would be correct:
np.float32_t[:] (using float_32). will update the answer accordingly.